Pitch accent of -り adverbs
This is a followup to the question For which parts of speech does a 平板/heiban–vs–尾高/odaka pitch accent contrast (word-final H(-H) vs H(-L)) exist? asked by Lover of Structure
.
I'm wondering if there are any ways to predict what the pitch accent is for adverbs, specifically, ones ending in り. I know that adverbs can sometimes be followed by the particle と, e.g. ぴたり or ぴたりと, so in theory, I assume there could be a pitch drop before the と. I saw that Wiktionary marks the accent of ぴたり as either pitaꜜri or pitariꜜ. The same two options are shown for がたり. How common is either pronunciation of these words? Is there some kind of rule for when adverbs can be odaka, or is it unpredictable like it is for nouns?

I've noticed that all the four-mora versions of ～り adverbs, like ぴったり, すっかり, きっちり, etc. are all nakadaka with a downstep after the third mora. Meanwhile, the three-mora versions, like ぴたり, すかり, きちり, etc. are listed (in Daijirin, at least) as having a downstep after either the second or the third mora, but without clarifying what conditions might cause one pattern or the other.  I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect that the difference for the three-mora versions might be whether or not you're using the adverbial particle と.  Curious what others have to say.

According to 新明解 for three mora 〜り adverbs that take can と can be either 中高 or 尾高 with either one being interchangeable it seems.
When it comes to choosing between to say it 中高 or 尾高, either sounds natural to me. Personally I say it 中高 almost always since it overlaps with four mora 〜り adverbs that take can と and is said -2 中高. So really all you need to remember is -2 for 〜り adverbs regardless of mora count and you should get something acceptable.
